# I don't understand GNU g++ compiler error "cc1plus: fatal error: ..."

Tags: c++, ubuntu-14.04, gnu-make, gnu, netbeans-8

I'm in the final stages (I hope) of porting an old Windows XP C/C++ program to LINUX.  I edited and tested a C++ class in the file DateTime.cpp.  In my test project it worked so I applied the edits to my working project.  When I make the project I get an error that I don't understand:

```
"/usr/bin/make" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/programmer/NetBeansProjects/Flight4'
"/usr/bin/make"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/flight4
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/programmer/NetBeansProjects/Flight4'
mkdir -p build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86
rm -f "build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/DateTime.o.d"
g++ -ffreestanding   -c -include /usr/local/include -MMD -MP -MF "build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/DateTime.o.d" -o build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/DateTime.o DateTime.cpp
cc1plus: fatal error: /usr/local/include: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

/usr/local/include exists; DateTime.cpp and DateTime.hpp are in the local project directory

```
/home/programmer/NetBeansProjects/Flight4
```

The project uses a couple of .so libraries in /usr/local/lib with their header files in /usr/local/include.

I've not coded in C/C++ for about 5 years now and when I did I used a RAD so I'm not skilled with makefiles.

Edit:  Etan's comment was right on the button: I had added /usr/local/bin to the wrong spot in the properties wizard.  Moving it to the correct field in the NetBeans Properties wizard fixed the problem.

Comment: The `-include` argument tells gcc to include its argument as an `#include`d header file but `/usr/local/include` isn't a file (the error does seem a bit misleading there).

Comment: Isn't `/usr/local/include` in the default header search path? Otherwise see `-I`.

Comment: You probably meant -isystem instead of -include